# Не получается запустить React (JS). Выдает ошибку SyntaxError. Что делаю неправильно?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

Windows XP
node v 4.1.1
npm 2.14.3

Как рекомендовано выполняю две команды (my-applaka - назвал приложение):

1. npm install -g create-react-app
2. create-react-app my-applaka

Но у меня ничего не получилось. После первой команды - всё ок вроде, а после второй выдает ошибку.
Что делать? Какой-то определенный синтаксис нужен? Не подскажите?

Что значит выражение: "const { init } = require('./createReactApp')"? Может это подсказка?

Ещё один момент, установку новейших программ не рассматриваем в вопросе - нужно как-то справится с имеющимися данными (Windows XP). Но как?
[image: Пытаюсь использовать React]

Comment: Обновляйтесь. WinXP и node4 давно вышли тз поддержки

Comment: Для такого синтаксиса нужно как минимум node 10, я не уверен чтт оно заработает на WinXP.

Comment: Попробуйте более старую версию `npm install -g create-react-app@1.5.2`. Последний релиз node v4 вышел 3 года назад, следовательно версии пакетов нужно искать для этого периода.